# C++: Can I have non-static member variable templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a bit of code that requires me to have a lot of `std::array`s in a container class. These arrays are all of varying sizes (all consecutive from 2-16, if that matters), and there is exactly one of each size. I want to put them in a container class, and be able to access them with templates.

It's probably easier to explain with code. I want something like this:

```
class ContainerClass {

public:
   // I want to declare some number of arrays right here, all of different
   // sizes, ranging from 2-16. I'd like to be able to access them as
   // arr<2> through arr<16>.

   // This code gives a compiler error, understandably. 
   // But this is what I'd think it'd look like.
   template <size_t N> // I also need to find a way to restrict N to 2 through 16.
   std::array<int, N> arr;

   // An example method of how I want to be able to use this.
   template <size_t N>
   void printOutArr() {
       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
           std::cout << arr<N>[i] << std::endl;
       }
   }
};
```

I'd like the code to expand out as if it just had 15 arrays in it, from 2-16. Like this, but with templates:

```
class ContainerClass {

public:
    std::array<int, 2> arr2;
    std::array<int, 3> arr3;
    std::array<int, 4> arr4;
    std::array<int, 5> arr5;
   // ... and so on.
};
```

From what I understand, C++ supports variable templates, but it seems like it's only for static members in classes. Is there an alternative that could behave similarly (preferably with as little overhead as possible)?

If you need more information, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want your class members to depend on a template argument then the whole class has to be a template. I'm not sure I can visualize how you would specify template arguments if individual members could have their own template arguments.

Comment: It sounds like you may want `arr` to be a tuple of arrays.

Comment: if you write out the members, then having a templated member function like your `printOutArr` is straightforward in case you worry about the code duplication of the member functions...

Comment: You could probably write a templated type that creates a tuple or array of arrays of the desired sizes. It should be doable using generator sequences.

Comment: If you don't need `std::array` it is trivial to do this with a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I have non-static member variable templates?

No.

However, you can use templates to generate a list of members like you describe. Here is an example using recursive inheritance:

```
template<class T, std::size_t base, std::size_t size>
class Stair;

template<class T, std::size_t base>
class Stair<T, base, base> {};

template<class T, std::size_t base, std::size_t size>
class Stair : Stair<T, base, size - 1> {
protected:
    std::array<T, size> arr;
public:
    template<std::size_t s>
    std::array<T, s>& array() {
        return Stair<T, base, s>::arr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stair<int, 2, 10> s;
    auto& arr = s.array<9>();
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! I had to also define a helper struct that would recursively iterate over all of the arrays, but doing it wasn't hard after seeing this answer, and about this sort of template recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have a solution using recursive templates and [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple). I compiled and tested it using gcc 7.3.0.

This makes me feel dirty, but it seems to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// Forward declare A since there is a circular dependency between A and Arrays
template <size_t size, size_t start, typename... T>
struct A;

// If size is greater than start define a type that is an A::ArrayTuple from the
// next step down (size - 1) otherwise type is void
template <size_t size, size_t start, typename E, typename... T>
struct Arrays {
    using type = typename std::conditional<(size > start),
        typename A<size-1, start, E, T...>::ArrayTuple,
        void
    >::type;
};

// Use template recursion to begin at size and define std::array<int, size>
// to add to a tuple and continue marching backwards (size--) until size == start
// When size == start take all of the std::arrays and put them into a std::tuple
//
// A<size, start>::ArrayTuple will be a tuple of length (size - start + 1) where
// the first element is std::array<int, start>, the second element is
// std::array<int, start + 1> continuing until std::array<int, size>
template <size_t size, size_t start, typename... T>
struct A {
    using Array = typename std::array<int, size>;

    using ArrayTuple = typename std::conditional<(size == start),
        typename std::tuple<Array, T...>,
        typename Arrays<size, start, Array, T...>::type
    >::type;
};

// This specialization is necessary to avoid infinite template recursion
template <size_t start, typename... T>
struct A<0, start, T...> {
    using Array = void;
    using ArrayTuple = void;
};

template <size_t size, size_t start = 1>
class Container {
public:
    using ArrayTuple = typename A<size, start>::ArrayTuple;

    // Shorthand way to the get type of the Nth element in ArrayTuple
    template <size_t N>
    using TupleElementType = typename
        std::tuple_element<N-start, ArrayTuple>::type;

    ArrayTuple arrays_;

    // Returns a reference to the tuple element that has the type of std::array<int, N>
    template <size_t N>
    TupleElementType<N>& get_array() {
        // Static assertion that the size of the array at the Nth element is equal to N
        static_assert(std::tuple_size< TupleElementType<N> >::value == N);
        return std::get<N-start>(arrays_);
    }

    // Prints all elements of the tuple element that has the type of std::array<int, N>
    template <size_t N>
    void print_array() {
        auto& arr = get_array<N>();
        std::cout << "Array Size: " << arr.size() << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    // Create a new Container object where the arrays_ member will be
    // a tuple with 15 elements:
    // std::tuple< std::array<int, 2>, std::array<int, 3> ... std::array<int, 16> >
    Container<16,2> ctr;

    auto& arr2 = ctr.get_array<2>();

    arr2[0] = 20;
    arr2[1] = 21;

    //ctr.print_array<1>(); // Compiler error since 1 < the ctr start (2)
    ctr.print_array<2>(); // prints 20 and 21
    ctr.print_array<3>(); // prints 3 zeros
    ctr.print_array<16>(); // prints 16 zeros
    //ctr.print_array<17>(); // Compiler error since 17 > the ctr size (16)

    //int x(ctr.arrays_); // Compiler error - uncomment to see the type of ctr.arrays_

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output from the compiler if I uncomment that line where I try to declare `int x` showing the type of `ctr.arrays_`:

```
so.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
so.cpp:90:22: error: cannot convert ‘Container<16, 2>::ArrayTuple {aka std::tuple<std::array<int, 2>, std::array<int, 3>, std::array<int, 4>, std::array<int, 5>, std::array<int, 6>, std::array<int, 7>, std::array<int, 8>, std::array<int, 9>, std::array<int, 10>, std::array<int, 11>, std::array<int, 12>, std::array<int, 13>, std::array<int, 14>, std::array<int, 15>, std::array<int, 16> >}’ to ‘int’ in initialization
     int x(ctr.arrays_); // Compiler error - uncomment to see the type of ctr.arrays_
```