# Can we not declare template members inside c++?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

see the below situation:
I wanted to make the pointer declaration generic but it throws the error : member 'b_pointer' declared as a template. Is there any way this can be achieved ?

```
class A {

protected: 
template<class x> x *b_pointer;          //this throws an error
B *b_pointer;                            //this does not throw an error
{;
```

Comment: What does "make the pointer declaration generic" mean to you?

Comment: Asking people to read your flawed code and see your intent is often no more successful than asking your compiler to read your flawed code and produce the executable you intended. Please try to describe in words your situation. The code should serve merely as a backup illustration, not as the primary means of communication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++: Can I have non-static member variable templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857352/c-can-i-have-non-static-member-variable-templates)

Answer (score 0):

declare a template class instead

```
template<class T>
class A {
    T* p;
};
```

Comment: But this cannot be done inside the class ? there is no other way of doing this other then templating the entire class ?

Comment: No way. However you can declare a static template member variable.Look Mikel's comment under your question.@Mandar